# How to send push notifications to aliases of goroost

Tags: java, php, html

How to send push notifications to aliases or particular registered email address in goroost?

Comment: Please provide detailed questions with sample codes that you have tried

Answer (score 0):

To send push notification in go roost you have to follow goroost doc. So login in https://dashboard.goroost.com/ and open following url.

1. https://dashboard.goroost.com/dashboard/settings/settings-roost-js
2. Then paste the script on your head section.
3. Download Chrome Install Files and unzip in and paste it on your root folder.
   for example in php if your url is 127.0.0.1/test/test.html then paste the downloaded files in /var/www/test/ this folder. it means project root folder.
4. then read this doc 'http://docs.goroost.com/docs/specification' and serch Push To Segment on this and read for sending mail.
5. for sendind push notification you have to use your goroost dashbord from new notificaion section.
6. You are unable to see the subscribers mail.
7. you can send notification with the help of subscribers